# Losing Tracking data with reference content

Tags: marketing-cloud

We’ve just recognized, that when using a reference content block within content builder, all tracking data i.E. link clicks will be lost in email send report. Is there an way to get the data?

I actually see the referenced content block in the tracking send but so link clicks behind it.

Comment: Can you provide more information like error screenshot, code snippet etc?

Comment: Are you using a redirectto function for the hyperlinks?

Comment: @Michael H can you please post the error what error you getting

Answer (score 0):

The links seem to be trackable. For the testing, I created a test content with one link embedded. Then I referenced the content in Email via

> %%=ContentBlockbyID("26127")=%%

(this got autogenerated as soon as I referenced the content). When I did the send and clicked on the link, I can see one click count in tracking report.

Thanks

Chandan